# Breve not displaying inside of table in Bulgarian

Tags: font-encodings

I have text in Bulgarian. If if is not inside of table it works fine but when it is inside of table it is missing the breve e.g. й changes to и.

My Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\section*{Задача 1.}

Втори параграф от решението на Задача 1.
Това също е във втория параграф, въпреки че в .tex-файла е на нов ред.

\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} { 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X | }
  \hline
                45
             & Софтуерни технологии и дизайн (Software Technologies and Design)  & \href{https://fmi-plovdiv.org/index.jsp?ln=1\&id=1815}{Computer science}  \\       
\hline
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for including a minimal example document. I can't reproduce your problem though, with a current TeXLive distribution but can reproduce it on Overleaf.

Comment: But the problem is that pdfLaTeX isn't designed to work with Unicode characters. See [Wrong character written before usage of \DeclareUnicodeCharacter](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/624221). So you would probably be better of using LuaLaTeX and a proper opentype font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to Overleaf or tables.

The first instance is

U+0439 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SHORT I

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?tex-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

the second is

U+0438 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER I  U+0306 COMBINING BREVE

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%CC%86%D0%BD

It is not really feasible to make combining characters work with pdftex, always use the pre-composed forms.